# Trying to get list of Id's from list of objects in MVC controller

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

I'm working on setting up a list of all bank accounts and their corresponding transactions for users to see based on what "household" they're in. I can get the list of accounts just fine, but am having trouble getting the transactions.

```
var model = new DashboardViewModel();
var user = db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());

var houseAccounts = db.BankAccounts.Where
    (b => b.HouseholdId == user.MyHouseId).ToList();

model.BankAccounts = houseAccounts;

model.Transactions = db.Transactions.Where
    (t => t.BankAccountsId == houseAccounts.Id);
```

At `houseAccounts.Id`, I'm getting an error stating that "List does not contain a definition for 'Id'..."

Each BankAccount is assigned a HouseholdId, and each Transaction is assigned a BankAccountsId. All objects in my db have an Id number created by the classes I built. How might I go about getting it here?

Answer (score 0):

> At houseAccounts.Id, I'm getting an error stating that "List does not contain a definition for 'Id'..."

houseAccounts is a List of BankAccounts and List doesn't have a Id.
Actually each object in the List (BankAccout in this case) have a Id.

So if you want the ids from houseAccounts, you can do something like:

```
var houseAccountIdList = houseAccounts.Select(it => it.Id);
```

with the Id List in hands you can get the transactions like this:

```
model.Transactions = db.Transactions.Where(it => houseAccountIdList.contains(it.BankAccountsId));
```

Answer (score 0):

The type `houseAccounts` is a list of BankAccount and you definitely cannot get the property `Id` from it unless you reference an item on the list. Try below:

```
 foreach (var account in houseAccounts){
    //Retrieve and add transactions based on each individual list-item id
  model.Transactions.Add(db.Transactions.Where (t => t.BankAccountsId == account.Id));
  }
```